# Simple Pause Feature Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

So I am making a simple pause feature that when the mouse leaves the frame, it goes to a specific frame. Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
function enterFrame(e:Event){
}



stage.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, exitFrame);
function exitFrame(e:Event)
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Every time I reach this frame, it automatically sends me to frame 3. Did I not use `Event.EXIT_FRAME correctly?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is incorrect `EXIT_FRAME` and `ENTER_FRAME` runs every time your program starts and exits a new frame.

You would benefit more from using `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` if you would like an event when the mouse leaves the stage area.

Here is a link to the livedocs explaining mouse event functionality:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html